# ldap_search com ldap_get_entries não retorna nenhum valor

Tags: php

Estou fazendo **autenticação via LDAP**:

```
$server = '192.168.0.1';
$domain = '@meudom';
$port   = 389;
$auth_user  = 'usuario1';
$auth_pass  = '123';

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($server, $port) or die('Erro na conexão');
if (!$ldap_connection) exit('Falha na conexão');

ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $auth_user.$domain, $auth_pass);
if (!$bind) exit('Usuário e/ou senha incorreto(s)!');

$filter = "(uid={$auth_user})";
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, "(dc=meudom, dc=com)", $filter) or exit("Erro em search");
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);

ldap_close($ldap_connection);
```

---

*Vi alguns exemplos em pesquisas, mas todos quase que num padrão.*

Até a parte do `ldap_bind` está autenticando perfeitamente.

**O que gostaria, é trazer os dados do usuário, entre outras informações possíveis**, mas em `$filter`, já testei diversas formas:

- "(uid={$auth_user})"
- "(cn=*})"
- "(ou=*})"
- etc

Sempre o resultado de `print_r($entries)` é `Array ( [count] => 0 )`.

---

Não sei se realmente está algo incorreto na parte do `ldap_search` ou outro local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove os parenteses no search

`ldap_search($ldap_connection, "dc=meudom, dc=com", $filter) –`

Comment: Não funcionou. Está correta a parte `ldap_search($ldap_connection, "(dc=meudom, dc=com)", $filter)`?

Comment: Esta certo sim, vc consegue se conectar ao servidor ldap por outro programa ( ex AdExplorer ) para enxergar a estrutura?

Comment: Consigo! Acabei de testar.

Comment: remove os parenteses no search  ldap_search($ldap_connection, "dc=meudom, dc=com", $filter)

Comment: Cara acabei de testar isso, não tinha visto seu comentário rs... Mas é isso mesmo! Posta na resposta que já confirmo! Obrigado! ✌️

Comment: editei já, confirma ai :D